# Should I upgrade a Shield Talisman to level 2

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I upgraded a Guardian Amulet Lvl 2 (critical: protect) to a Shield Talisman (Auto: Protect) Lvl1.

It now has 600 EXP, and turns to a Lvl 2 at 1500 EPX.

Does it have any beneficial effect to upgrade it to Lvl 2? For example better protection, or longer duration of the effect?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't remember if the accessories have stats, as I played a long time ago. However if they do, I'd expect them to rise with the level.

The effect won't change from leveling up the item, however you would get more from dismantling a higher leveled item.

(Not setting this as an answer as I'm unsure).

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a Red Herring in relation to the *Treasure Hunter* Achievement/Trophy.

the description reads (at least on the PS3)

> Held every weapon and accessory.

and [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/928790-final-fantasy-xiii/faqs/58766) on gamefaqs says

> You only need to have owned every
>   weapon and accessory at SOME point in time

Now, according to [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/928790-final-fantasy-xiii/faqs/59331), the Shield Talisman has a Max Level of 2 but no Transformation Cataltst, much like some of the other Talismans.

Also, even if you have completed your inventory you have to go to see Bhakti in Oerba to actually get it as noted in my first link,

> To actually receive this trophy you
>   have to talk to Bhakti, so don't have a heart attack if you don't get it as
>   soon as your inventory is complete.

as such while trying to get the *Treasure Hunter* Achievement/Trophy by having some accessories which can go up to Level 2 and not getting the Achievement/Trophy until you see Bhakti the player can be tricked in thinking that they are missing a Transformation Cataltst meant for Talismans when this isn't the case.

As for [djsmiley2k's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106027/should-i-upgrade-a-shield-talisman-to-level-2#comment142089_106027), [this guide (G0900)](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/928790-final-fantasy-xiii/faqs/58716) says it's only worth if you dismantle started accessories and weapons (Max Level)

> It's only worth it if you dismantle starred accessories and weapons, because
>   that way you get the maximum amount of stuff back. Dismantling may give you
>   back items, materials, accessories, or weapons.

which for the Shield Talisman you get

- 10x Moistened Scale
- 5x Seapetal Scale
- 3x Crystal Oscillator

weather they are any good to you or not is up to you however alot of the [Gil Farming Suggestions](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/928790-final-fantasy-xiii/faqs/59442) don't make use of mass producing Max Leveled accessories and weapons and Selling them or their dismantled components (most are strait farming and selling off enemy drops which you could get from dismantling but be more efficent to get as drops)

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://guides.gamercorner.net/ffxiii/accessories/shield-talisman it doesn't seem to offer any additional benefits other than being able to sell it for more gil (not much more). 1,500 EXP will put it at Master level - not sure if that brings any benefits of it's own...it's been a while since I've played. According to the link above, you should be able to locate another Shield Talisman, so if you have the time and patience (and really want to know), you could carry 2 and upgrade one to Master and see if there is a difference.